# Environment Variable error while initializing kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, ubuntu-20.04

All,

I tried setting up Kubernetes on my two Ubuntu v20.0 using the below link -

> https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu

But I get an error when the Ubuntu was rebooted and since then I have not been able to proceed forward.

```
invalid variable assignment ignoring cgroup-driver=systemd/cgroup-driver=cgroupfs
```

The Docker info has the entry ***"Cgroup driver = cgroupfs"***

The below article mentions about configuring cgroup driver:

```
https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
rgn

Comment: Can you check not adding `Environment=”cgroup-driver=systemd/cgroup-driver=cgroupfs”` on `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issued to be with the various versions of the softwares/modules that are needed. I was able to find a simple installation steps to accomplish the same